# Trying to get my login php function to work

Tags: php, html, authentication, server

I have a code that takes a username and password and submits it to a server function. The server function trims the user name and password and converts the password to a MD5 Hash which it then compares to the MD5 hash that is in the database.

I cannot get this to work, I keep getting a error logging in username or password does not match.

My Login.Php and server code are below (I've trimmed the server code to show the needed functions).

```
<?PHP
require_once("../model/membersite_config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($fgmembersite->Login())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login-home.php");
   }
}

?>
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <header data-role="header">
        <h1>Food Loginator</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.localhost:8080/index.php" rel="external"  data-icon="home" data-theme="b" >Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.localhost:8080/view/login.php" rel="external"  data-icon="star" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-active">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.localhost:8080/view/register.php" rel="external" data-icon="grid" data-theme="b">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>

<!-- Form Code Start -->
<div id='fg_membersite'>
<form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<legend>Login</legend>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

<div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>

<div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='username' >UserName*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='password' >Password*:</label><br/>
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='login_password_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</div>
<div class='short_explanation'><a href='http://www.localhost:8080/view/reset-pwd-req.php' rel='external'>Forgot Password?</a></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<!-- client-side Form Validations:
Uses the excellent form validation script from JavaScript-coder.com-->

<script type='text/javascript'>
// <![CDATA[

    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("login");
    frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();

    frmvalidator.addValidation("username","req","Please provide your username");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("password","req","Please provide the password");

// ]]>
</script>
</div>
<!--
Form Code End (see html-form-guide.com for more info.)
-->

<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

**Membersite_config.PHP**

```
<?PHP
require_once("fg_membersite.php");

$fgmembersite = new FGMembersite();

//Provide your site name here
$fgmembersite->SetWebsiteName('localhost');

//Provide the email address where you want to get notifications
$fgmembersite->SetAdminEmail('Redacted');

//Provide your database login details here:
//hostname, user name, password, database name and table name
//note that the script will create the table (for example, fgusers in this case)
//by itself on submitting register.php for the first time
$fgmembersite->InitDB(/*hostname*/'localhost',
                      /*username*/'Redacted',
                      /*password*/'Redacted',
                      /*database name*/'diet_software',
                      /*table name*/'users');

//For better security. Get a random string from this link: http://tinyurl.com/randstr
// and put it here
$fgmembersite->SetRandomKey('qSRcVS6DrTzrPvr');

?>
```

**fg_membersite.php**

```
function Login()
    {
        if(empty($_POST['username']))
        {
            $this->HandleError("UserName is empty!");
            return false;
        }

        if(empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
            return false;
        }

        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
        if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($username,$password))
        {
            return false;
        }

        $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $username;

        return true;
    }
```

CheckLoginDB

```
function CheckLoginInDB($username,$password)
    {
        if(!$this->DBLogin())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
            return false;
        }          
        $username = $this->SanitizeForSQL($username);
        $pwdmd5 = md5($password);
        $qry = "Select name, email from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";

        $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);

        if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
        {
            $this->HandleError("Error logging in. The username or password does not match");
            return false;
        }

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


        $_SESSION['name_of_user']  = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['email_of_user'] = $row['email'];

        return true;
    }
```

SanitizeForSQL

```
function SanitizeForSQL($str)
    {
        if( function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ) )
        {
              $ret_str = mysql_real_escape_string( $str );
        }
        else
        {
              $ret_str = addslashes( $str );
        }
        return $ret_str;
    }
```

Handle Error

```
function HandleError($err)
    {
        $this->error_message .= $err."\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing CheckLoginInDB anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: Yep none of the above code is relevant. Problem is going to be in  `CheckLoginInDVB` function

Comment: You really [shouldn't use MD5 on passwords](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: @BenFried and MikeMiller
I attached the requested code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

In your `fg_membersite.php'`s *login()* function  on the line of `if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start();}` , the session fails to start. Move your `session_start();` at the top of PHP file after the `<?php`. It should be

**fg_membersite.php**

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    ...
    ...
    ...
    function Login()
    {
    `if(!isset($_SESSION)){

     //session_start(); <-- this will be moved at the top
      .....
      .....
     }`
      .....
      ......
     }  // end Login()
```

Comment: it still is having an error at the login. I know the db connection works because I can add users via the registration form.

Comment: It's hard to tell, the session is created outside the function so it's  just well , but one thing for sure the session won't start inside the function, but  again there a lot possibilities causing the errors,  Sir. it may be good at next time you post the errors also, so ppl can spot quickly.